# MySQL: Referencing various table IDs in one table

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I'm working on a project where people can receive infos about a football game (flight, hotel, sights, stadium). The site should also contain a list of appointments (When and where is my flight, where is my hotel, when do I have to go to the stadium ...) In my opinion it would be really cool, if you reference the flights,hotel,etc in this appointments table to present the user some additional info about this appointment

In general I could do s.th like

```
appointmentID | appointmentDate | appointmentDuration | flightID | hotelID | stadiumID
```

and fill the non needed values with NULL. But I think that isn't a good idea.

Also I could store them this way:

```
appointmentID | appointmentDate | appointmentDuration | appointmentType | appointmentTypeID
```

and fill appointmentType with the strings of the table (Hotels,Flights,...) and the appointmentTypeID with the ID of the appointmentType. But that way doesn't feels good.

So my question is: what would be the best way to save this values in a database?

EDIT: I know that the goal is to normalize the table. And in general I know which data I've to put in seperate tables. My question is how can I do it in this particular case

Comment: normalized. The more rows the better

Comment: I know that the default answer is "normalize it". The question is how, since there isn't much data that I can extract from the appointments. Creating extra tables for appointment_flights, appointment_hotels to put the appointmentID and the otherID in doesn't looks like a good idea

Comment: Best to think of a table as an object in oop rather than a hodgepodge of info that can be (A) incomplete, (B) n/a, (C) not scalable or flexible. I want to have an appt as you call it but I am going to a Yankees game and the Mets too. Oh, and I have 2 hotel chunks. I think you get the idea. Generally speaking, given the choice of going horizontal versus vertical, choose vertical.

Answer (score 0):

The first way seems like a better option.

I would have the following but I would add a reference table

Appointment_table
app_id
app_f_id (Referencing the id of flight table)
app_h_id (Referencing the id of hotel table)
app_s_id (Referencing the id of Stadium table)
app_ref_table (This would contain a unique generated reference because making use of the id will become problematic in the future as the id could stretch into the millions...)

Flight_table
f_id
f_carrier
f_date_booking
f_date_confirmed

Hotel_table
h_id
h_descripion
h_guests

Stadium_table
s_id
s_description

Every year the reference table will begin with sequence 1 or which ever you prefer. This is neat approach in my opinion to table structure.
Reference_table
r_id
r_year
r_sequence
r_app_id (The last id that had a reference number generated)